# Conflict my CSS with inbuilt Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have added my own marquee and related css in our website, but when I make that top bar with marquee position as fixed, So it will disturb my header CSS

Website URL: https://timesandtrendsacademy.com/. And when I am trying to make that Top-bar as a Sticky, So it will affect with my header css code and not showing properly.

```css
#top-bar{

background-color:#ef4d3b !important;
font-family: roboto,sans-serif !important;
position:fixed !important;
width:100%;
}
#top-bar p{
font-size: 16px;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-top:2px;
}
.btn-primary{
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-bar">
                <p>
                 <marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
                  <span>TTA's B.Sc In Fashion Designing Course Is Now Affiliated with Savitribai Phule Pune University</span>
                  <span><a href="http://www.ttafashioncollege.com/" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" target="_blank">Apply Now</a></span>
                 </marquee>
                </p>

</div>
```

To avoid confliction with css, What will be the full clean code.

Comment: Did I understood correctly: You want #top-bar fixed on top but without disrupting header?

Comment: Yes, Top-bar should be fixed on to while scrolling without disturbing other header css code.

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest solution would be like this:

```
#top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: 2;
}

body {
    margin-top: 34px;
}
```

This should make #top-bar appear on top and all other content is pushed down by the height of #top-bar. Also do not forget the z-index: 2 as you don't want other content to cover your #top-bar

Comment: It really works well in www.timesandtrendsacademy.com, And I have applied same for www.ttaindia.com, So the body didn't take margin from top why?

Comment: The thing with your second website is that, the #masthead has position: absolute. because of this, it ignores margin-top on body, and pushes only content. You can remove position: absolute from #masthead and padding-top from .content-pusher .This way, it should all work fine. ( At least it works when editing in code inspector )

Comment: Then what should be the position for masthead?, I have set to none. But it will not affect. Please elaborate

Comment: Just don't set position at all. These are my changes: https://imgur.com/a/XYsrOag

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer as correct if you are happy with results. it would make me happy.